# Get rank of player from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I found some good answers for this question, but I can't really get them to work.

I wan't to get a players rank from a hiscore table.

```
id   name   score

1    John    10
2    Linda   5
3    Emmy    25
```

I want to pass in a name in the query (Linda) and get her rank (She only have 5 points in the table above), and get her rank (nr 3).

I found a similar question with this answer, but don't understand it:

```
SELECT  uo.*, 
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    users ui
    WHERE   (ui.points, ui.id) >= (uo.points, uo.id)
    ) AS rank
   FROM    users uo
   WHERE   id = @id
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the answer you have works fine.  Count all users with a score greater than or equal to the specified user's score.  (could change to just greater than if you want, possibly adding 1 as well).  Then change the outer where to WHERE name = 'Linda' for your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT name, score, rank FROM
  (SELECT *, @r:=@r + 1 rank FROM table_name ORDER BY score DESC) t1,
  (SELECT @r:=0) t2
WHERE name = 'Linda'
```

Comment: It will fail in case of ties!

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT (COUNT(*) + 1) AS rank FROM hiscore WHERE score > (SELECT score FROM hiscore WHERE name = 'Linda')`

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT rank, name, score 
FROM 
    (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, score 
     FROM players 
     ORDER BY score DESC)
```